# How can I utilize the same credential handler configuration for my application's container in generating new password hashes?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have the context for my Web application defined similar to

```html
<Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://greensuite.database.windows.net:1433;database=greensuite_db;user=greensuiteapp@greensuite;password=K1B&amp;i9i8*1id^dUzhsv^;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;" userTable="[User]" userNameCol="email" userCredCol="password" userRoleTable="UserGlobalRole" roleNameCol="role">
       <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" encoding="UTF-8" algorithm="SHA-512" iterations="1000000" saltLength="20" />
    </Realm>
</Context>
```

What can I put in an action listener to be able to do something like:

```
String passwordHash = credentialHandler.mutate(newPassword);
```

where `credentialHandler` is a `CredentialHandler` instance that applies to the request being processed.

The point is to have the configuration in one place, the context configuration instead of duplicating the configuration in the context configuration and in the code generating and storing a new hash.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to follow the indications given in Christopher Schultz's [slides from ApacheCon 2016](http://people.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202016/Seamless%20Upgrades%20for%20Credential%20Security%20in%20Apache%20Tomcat.pdf). Supposing you don't object to referencing Tomcat 8.x `catalina.jar` in your build process, first `import` the required classes:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.apache.catalina.CredentialHandler;
import org.apache.catalina.Globals;
```

Then, getting the `CredentialHandler` is a simple matter of using the correct key to look up the `ServletContext`'s attributes:

```
public static CredentialHandler getCredentialHandler(final ServletContext context) {
  return (CredentialHandler) context.getAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER);
}
```

The slides give an alternative method using reflection to avoid having to include `catalina.jar` in your compilation classpath.

**Beware** though that this only works if you have a single unnested `<Realm>` configured in your `context.xml`. If you are wrapping your `<Realm>` with a `LockoutRealm`, for instance, the lookup will only consider the outermost `Realm` returning a generic `CredentialHandler`, instead of drilling down to the `Realm` containing the `CredentialHandler` you configured.

Comment: Nice answer. How do you get around the problem you describe in your last paragraph where it only returns a generic CredentialHandler? I have a LockoutRealm and NestedCredentialHandler and am having that exact problem.

Comment: Depending on implementation details is always fragile. I've reconsidered a bit after writing this, and in another project I opted for copying the hashing logic in `CredentialHandler` into my own class. The danger there is that the configuration in the Context and in my own code drift apart and become incompatible, but it's the lesser of two evils, I think.