# how to use digest.sh in embedded-tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, embedded-tomcat-8, embedded-tomcat

I know that `$CATALINE_HOME/bin/digest.sh` is used to generate hashed passwords which can be used in `tomcat_users.xml` but how can I implement the same behavior where I am using embedded tomcat in the project as it doesn't have `bin/digest.sh`?

UPDATE:

I found that `RealmBase.java` of tomcat has a method `digest()` which does equivalent to what digest.sh does, however, it's deprecated since tomcat 9 and I am using tomcat 9. Does anyone know what the new implementation for this method is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I utilize the same credential handler configuration for my application's container in generating new password hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490893/how-can-i-utilize-the-same-credential-handler-configuration-for-my-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central method for dealing with hashed passwords is [`CredentialHandler#mutate`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/CredentialHandler.html#mutate-java.lang.String-), which is also the one used by `digest.sh`. It transforms the supplied password into its stored form.

You can retrieve the `CredentialHandler` in many ways:

- from the `Tomcat` object, using `tomcat.getEngine().getRealm().getCredentialHandler()`. For this to work you need to start the `Realm` if it is not running,
- from a servlet, by retrieving the `Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER` ("org.apache.catalina.CredentialHandler") servlet context attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`digest.sh` is used to generate password hashes. If you need to generate password hashes, just download tomcat archive from the Tomcat's homepage and run the script.

Embedded Tomcat does not have this script.

Comment: I have a project that uses embedded-tomcat, now the requirement is to encrypt the password for tomcat-users.xml, programmatically I was able to set the plain-text password using tomcat-embed api and also if manually set the hashed password I am able to fetch using `org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler;` class but is there any similar class which encrypts the string similar to what digest.sh is doing manually.